# Geolocation get location async cannot be awaited

Tags: c#, asynchronous, geolocation

I am creating a c# form application(It's important to note that it's not a mobile app cause I think that is part of the issue). I am trying to use the Windows devices geolocation libraries and I am running into the issue that the code given on the microsoft website doesn't work.

```
            GeolocationAccessStatus accessstatus = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();
```

This code should work fine but I get the error "IAsyncOperation does not contain a method for getawaiter and no extension method accepting a first argument of  IAsyncOperation" What is causing this. I know it says that you need using system in the declarations but I have that so it can't be that. What is causing the issue? Note the method it's called in is `private async static void MainGeomethod()` so it can't be that either. Any advice as to what is causing this issue?

Comment: You need access to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582011

Comment: what does this method `RequestAccessAsync()` returns? post it's definition

Comment: @Rahul Looks like it's `IAsyncOperation<GeolocationAccessStatus>`.  Which I don't think is compatible with `await`.

Comment: @juharr you should be able to somehow run an IAsyncOperation as a task which can be waited on. So IAsyncOperation op could be run as op.AsTask()

Comment: @SLaks How can I get that library? I tried nuget but those packages are broken from what I can tell....

Comment: @juharr: There is an extension method for that.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582011

Answer (score 1):

After some looking I found that the assembly file I needed was actaully not on the list of possible references but had to be found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll