# Getting around App Container c#

Tags: c#, windows, geolocation

I have a very simple question and I feel like there should be an easy answer. How can I use a method that is only supposed to be used by a windows 10 app in just a regular application? The method in particular is Geolocator.RequestAccesssync which refuses to be run unless I was using a windows universal app. Any advice?

Comment: did you not asked the same question few minutes back? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750835/geolocation-get-location-async-cannot-be-awaited?noredirect=1#comment64875558_38750835

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Per [MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.requestaccessasync.aspx):

> **Requirements (Windows 10 device family)**
>
> Device family: Universal, introduced version 10.0.10240.0

The API simply doesn't exist in older OS versions. It's not there to call.